# How to populate geography point using ST_MakePoint(long, lat)

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, postgis-2.0

I have a table called `customer_campaign`, and there is an empty column `geom(geography)` in it. So I want to fill it up by using `ST_MakePoint(long, lat)` in `PostGIS`, `lat and long` are two columns in the `customer_campaign` table. I tried the following query:

```
SELECT ST_MakePoint(customer_campaign.long, customer_campaign.lat);
```

But returns an error. How do I populate `geography` column with `ST_Make(long, lat)` in `PostGIS` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast from the output of `ST_MAKE()` which is a `geometry` to the `geography` data type.

This casting is done by using the `::` operator.

The following command should work: 
`UPDATE customer_campaign set geom=ST_MakePoint(customer_campaign.long, customer_campaign.lat)::geography;`